# Use of ORDER BY returns no result

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an entity defined as:

```
a    Integer
b    Float
type     String 
type     STRING  <--- Indexed property
```

I run a query with no sorting, and it returns results.

```
SELECT * FROM com_MyDomain WHERE type = 'GENERAL'
```

If I add sorting, the query returns no result.

```
SELECT * FROM com_MyDomain WHERE type = 'GENERAL' ORDER BY b, a
```

I also have an index (Serving status in app engine console) defined as:

```
<datastore-index kind="com_MyDomain"
    ancestor="false" source="manual">
    <property name="type" direction="asc" />
    <property name="b" direction="asc" />
    <property name="a" direction="asc" />
</datastore-index>
```

Comment: Do your entities really have `type` defined twice or is that a typo in the question? I also notice your index is `type`, `b`, `a` whereas your select is `type`, `a`, `b`.

Comment: I copied the entity from the app engine console. The second `type` is the indexed property. It's a typo in my select.

Comment: If you're getting no results, it's likely that either the entities don't contain the columns you're ordering on or the index doesn't contain the entities. Is the index built?

Comment: The index is serving. BTW I have the same issue on dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that your entities don't have a value for b or a.

As written here :

> > Entities lacking a property named in the query are ignored
> >
> > Entities of the same kind need not have the same properties. To be eligible as a query result, an entity must possess a value (possibly null) for every property named in the query's filters and sort orders. If not, the entity is omitted from the indexes used to execute the query and consequently will not be included in the query's results.

(from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries  under 'Restriction on queries')

so the only logical thing seems that your data doesn't have a or b filled.